# How to route original dataflow if JSON response from InvokeHTTP contains value

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to send a dataflow to a webservice which will then respond based on the content of the dataflow. So it might respond with a JSON that says {'Errors':'None'} or {'Errors':'5'}. I would like to then use this information to continue processing the original dataflow if no errors are found, orlog the information if any errors are found. My question is, how can I route based on the values in the JSON response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use EvaluateJsonPath to get the value of `Errors` into an attribute, then RouteOnAttribute to send the different values down different paths.

Alternatively you could use QueryRecord with queries like `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE Errors = 'None'`. Each query gets its own downstream relationship, so it has the effect of routing in this case.